# How to install an Android .APK using Python code?

Tags: android, python, apk, android-install-apk

Is there a way to programmatically install an Android .apk in Python?

Could you please show me how? I'm new to Python.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here http://www.ubergizmo.com/how-to/how-to-install-apk-files-sideloading-on-android/

Comment: @piotrek1543 thank you for your effort, but what I want to know is how to install those apk's using a Python code

Comment: Sorry gu, but even here: http://android.kivy.org/about is used Android Debug Bridge instead of code

Comment: Are you looking for something like `subprocess.call("adb install path-to-file.apk ")` ?

Comment: @Swing yes, that's what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Swing mentioned in his comment, `subprocess.call("adb install path-to-file.apk ")` solves the issue.

Comment: would you need to add adb to the path before doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I have designed a python script to automate download of apk files and reinstall them.
I have coded a wrapper/adapter of the ADB process in python by using:

```
subprocess.run()
```

Public repo is Xackage there:
[Xackage on GitHub](https://github.com/tbremard/Xackage)

I did also a Youtube video where I use Xackage to automate the pull of all ThirdParty Apk, before making a factory reset and re pushing all of them.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UT4ZoD5rI2U